# Angular 2 - NgFor not updating view

Tags: javascript, angular, components, ngfor

I am working on angular 2 project and I am having an issue when I am trying to change the list . NgFor not recognizing the changes , and displaying only the list loaded at first time .

here is an example code when I am loading all list and imminently after loading I reset it with null . the view still displaying all the list ...

this is my component constructor for example :

```
 constructor( private songService : SongService)
    this.songService.getSongs()
         .subscribe(songsList => {
             this.songs = songsList;
         });

    this.songs = null;

}
```

and this is the html :

```
<div class="row">
    <div  *ngFor= "let song of songs" class="col-md-4">
     <app-song-item [song]="song"></app-song-item>
    <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your whole code, not an example. If you want to post an example, then make a MCVE.

Comment: You are trying to display data which is not there yet

Comment: @trichetriche this is all code

Comment: Do you want to display "songsList" in the UI? or
You dont want to ?
You are saying, "I am loading all list and imminently after loading I reset it with null . the view still displaying all the list ".

Comment: Set a breakpoint at this.songs = songsList (inside the subscribe) and one at this.songs = null to see in which order the songlist is changed. The subscribe callback is probably called after resetting the list to null.

Comment: `here is an example code when I am loading all list`. I don't see how you update your list. Anyways, I'll make an answer, you'll adapt it to your case.

Comment: @BasavarajBhusani I just notice the view does not change when list is changing so I am trying display the list and immediately after that erase it . btw its also not working with variable type number that I am binding to the view , I printed to console , and it says that a change occurred but the view not changing

Comment: You should do this..
`
songs = [];
 constructor( private songService : SongService) {
    this.songService.getSongs()
         .subscribe(songsList => {
             this.setSongs(songsList);
         });

}

setSongs () {
this.songs = songsList;
}
`


clearing songs using   `this.songs = null;`  doesnt work, as it works only once during constructor

Answer (score 6):

Loops in Angular sometimes screw up, in the way that they don't track your items the way you would want it to.

To prevent that, you can use a custom track by function like this

```
<div *ngFor="let song of songs; let i = index; trackBy: customTB" class="col-md-4">
```

In your TS

```
customTB(index, song) { return `${index}-${song.id}`; }
```

This way, you set up a custom trackBy function, that will update your view (the view wasn't getting updated because the tracking ID wasn't changing).

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you are still seeing your list is because it is async. You can't be sure when the subscribe method is executed. It can be be direct, within seconds, take hours or not even at all. So in your case you are resetting the list before you are even getting one.

```
constructor( private songService : SongService)
  this.songService.getSongs()
    .subscribe(songsList => { //Might take a while before executed.
      this.songs = songsList;
    });

  this.songs = null; //executed directly
}
```

The above explanation might be the cause of your problem, but there could also be another explanation. The constructor is only called when the component is created. Changing a router parameter doesn't necessarily create a component. Angular might re-use the component if it can.

Comment: thank you I understand what are you saying , I also try do it with variable type of number. on the constructor number = 5, and on other function I change it to 6 , the console shows that number is now 6 but the view not changing . and of course in the html I bind the number {{number}}

Comment: Maybe you can create a working example demonstrating your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of null you should set an empty array, also have it inside a method, otherwise it never gets called

```
 this.songService.getSongs()
         .subscribe(songsList => {
             this.songs = songsList;
         });
clear(){
    this.songs = [];
}
```

Comment: thank you , but its not solving the problem , still shows all list

Comment: you have to call the method from the template

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
constructor(private songService: SongService) {
    this.songService.getSongs()
        .subscribe(songsList => {
            this.songs = songsList;
            this.reset();
        });
}

reset() {
    this.songs = [];
}
```

Comment: this is wokring , but in any other place I am trying to do it its not working. as I commented in other posts I also tried with number initialized with 5 and bind it in the html code,   in other function I increase the number but the view does not recognize the change